# Disk Clean Up Tool for Windows Server

Tags: disk-analysis, windows-server

I'm looking for a disk clean up tool to free up disk space on Windows Server 2008, 2008 R2, and 2014. Something like CCleaner but more through. Either freeware or payware under $200 but must be company license because I need this on 10-15 servers.

Comment: Though CCleaner seems to be a well-known product, it would be better to [edit] your question and include your specific requirements explicitly. You can take a look at [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) for orientation. Examples: should it have a dupe-finder, registry cleaner, temp-file-remover, ..., and what is your idea of being "more through"? These additional details certainly will improve your chance for (good) answers.

Comment: Right click on the drive -> Properties -> Cleanup?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements, you could use a PowerShell script to empty specific directories or delete temp files etc. You could even set this up as a scheduled task.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your requirements are, but here are a few options:

- https://www.bleachbit.org/ (FOSS) - alternative to CCleaner - don't think is 'more thorough'.
- https://windirstat.net/ (FOSS) - Visualize where storage is used, so it will be easier to cleanup.
- https://www.bcuninstaller.com/ (FOSS) - Software oriented, uninstaller and leftover cleaner - has the ability to show software by the space it consumes.

Of course, if it's just cleaning up temp folders and such, right-click on a drive, properties and then choosing cleanup is probably the 'best' as in safest solution - as it is an OS feature.

If none of these are of any help, please elaborate what exactly you're looking for.